# como crear un evento CustomEvent en una clase en JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript

estoy intentado crear un evento con CustomEvent dentro de una clase en JavaScript.

```
class MyClass {

constructor(options) {
  this.el = options.element;
  this.like();
}
  
  like(){
    
const event = new CustomEvent('awesome', { detail: {
  current:n
}});

const container = document.querySelector(this.el);
container.dispatchEvent(event);

  }
  }
```

y lo quiero llamar asi (quisiera de esta manera) :

```
const myclass = new MyClass({
  element:'.my-class'
});

myclass.addEventListener('awesome', function (e) { /* ... */
  console.log(e.detail);
});
```

se agradece por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `addEventListener` es propio de los elementos del `DOM`, por lo que una forma de conseguir lo que buscas sería:

- En el método `constructor` establecemos `this.el` igual al DOMElement que se encuentre usando el selector indicado
- En el método `like` disparamos el evento presonalizado sobre `this.el`
- Posterior a la creación de la instancia `myclass` utilizamos el método `addEventListener` sobre `myclass.el`
- Por último, llamamos al método `like` para disaprar el evento.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
class MyClass {

  constructor(options) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(options.element);
  }

  like() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('awesome', {detail: {current: '?'}});
    this.el.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}


const myclass = new MyClass({
  element: '.my-class'
});

myclass.el.addEventListener('awesome', e => console.log(e.detail));
myclass.like();
```

```html
<div class="my-class"></div>
```

**PD**: Si quisieras hacer `myclass.addEventListener`, entonces deberías crear dicho método en la `class MyClass`